# Fiber Home AN5506-04-FA router/modem has no port forwarding option

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm trying to learn some things that involve port forwarding, but I noticed that my router (Fiber Home AN5506-04-FA) doesn't have some options that some guides pointed out.

I'm trying this guide https://portforward.com/fiber-home/an5506-04-f2/

which is the closest of my model, since I wasn't able to find an exact one.

Here's a screenshot of where there should be a "Port Forwarding" option:

[image: Image of the page where "Port Forwarding" should be.]

The option should be in the left panel menu.

So, my question is: Is there any way to enable this option? If not how can I achieve the same effect without this option?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if your router/modem doesn’t have those options you are out of luck. Your best option would be to purchase a stand alone router and connect that to the Fiber Home router/modem in bridge mode which would disable the router portion of that device and let the standalone router do all the work. More flexible and more choices as to what you can do especially if you can flash with open source firmware like [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com).

Comment: Your screenshot clearly indicates you are able to create a firewall rule.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks I'll look about this options. If there's no other solution in some time please post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Ramhound My question is if there's a way for me to open a server (I hope I'm using the right words) so I can try to communicate with my computer otside my network, which is the reason I want to do port forwarding.
Thanks!

Comment: @Float07 Simply click on Add.  Instead of separating out DNAT and SNAT, it's using a single option to add either